# ar-drone module not found, where to place it?

Tags: javascript, ar.drone

I am trying to hack my ar drone 2.0, i am following this tutorial: http://www.instructables.com/id/Autonomous-AR-Parrot-Drone-20-Flying/?ALLSTEPS

I have installed node on my `D:` drive and installed the ar-drone module on in the `node_modules` folder. I tried the

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
```

command it says "undefined". I tried writing a .js file and executing that from the cmd, and it responds with

> "Error cannot find module 'ar-drone'"

I moved the ar-drone folder to different places(in the node_modules folder but also in the folder where i saved the .js file) but my drone is still standing on the ground with all four of his legs :(

I am of course connected to the drones WiFi, but I don't think the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't find the ar-drone, you need to execute this line again and see there are no errors:

```
npm install ar-drone
```

Comment: Remove the ar-drone module folder from everywhere; node handles folders for you, all you need is to use the command line.

Comment: still the same error, should i try to install node on the c: or is that unnecessary? thanks